# Convert Vec<Vec<u8>> to &[&[u8]]

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes some number of byte strings: `&[&[u8]]` but want to call it with an argument of type `Vec<Vec<u8>>`. Calling the function like this:

```
let foo: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
bar(&foo[..]);
```

converts `foo` to a slice but not the values it contains. Is there a way to do this conversion easily and efficiently? Or can I change the type of the function argument to avoid cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this case without allocating an additional `Vec` is to use [`AsRef<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#impl-AsRef%3C%5BT%5D%3E-4):

```
fn bar<S: AsRef<[u8]>>(args: &[S]) {
    // ...
}
```

Inside the function, you can use `.as_ref()` to convert each of the arguments to a `&[u8]`.

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4beaf127ed45cb6c61651e1ad3f2923a))

Answer (score 2):

From a memory perspective this doesn't make much sense. To create a slice, the data being sliced must first exist in memory. However to take a slice of `&[u8]`, you first need to have some data structure like `Vec<&[u8]>` to take the slice from.

In other words to do this, you need to allocate space for `Vec<&[u8]>` or `[&[u8]; N]` and fill it with slices first. This somewhat defeats the purpose of using slices since slices are meant to existing reference memory in place. Consider using `&[Vec<u8>]` for your function instead.

If having slices in the second layer is important or you are unable to edit the function you can do the following to convert `Vec<Vec<u8>>` to `&[&[u8]]`:

```rust
let foo: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();

// Allocate Vec of references to slices
let tmp: Vec<&[u8]> = foo.iter().map(|x| &x[..]).collect();

// Take slice of temporary Vec
bar(&tmp[..]);
```